# Webpage along with image download using python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp

I am trying to write a code in python 2.7.13 as part of a homework which should download a webpage pointed by a specified URL and all the image objects referenced by that URL. It has been instructed strongly that I use socket programming to perform the task. I am not allowed to use any higher libraries such as: urllib2, urrlib3 or so on.

I have written a simple code which downloads webpage as a html file using socket programming and I was able to download a specific webpage in my laptop. I also tried to download any image on that webpage but it doesn't work apparently. If there is an image on the webpage, the saved html file doesn't display that image. My code is inefficient in a sense that it does not provide an option to specify a URL by the user. How can I modify the code so that it will take an input URL from the user and download the webpage along with all the associated image objects existent on that webpage.

Below is my code:

```
import socket

# Set up a TCP/IP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect as client to a selected server
# on a specified port

s.connect(("www.automatetheboringstuff.com",80))

# Protocol exchange - sends and receives
s.send("GET /chapter16/ HTTP/1.0\n\n")
file=open('download_webpage.html','w')
picture = "";
while True:
        resp = s.recv(4096)
        if resp == "": break
        print resp,
        file.write(resp)
        picture = picture + resp

# Close the connection when completed
file.close
s.close()

# Look for the end of the header (2 CRLF)
pos = picture.find("\r\n\r\n");
print 'Header length',pos
print picture[:pos]

# Skip past the header and save the picture data
picture = picture[pos+4:]
fhand = open("stuff.jpg","w")
fhand.write(picture);
fhand.close()
```

Comment: You must now extract the urls of images from your html file. Have a look at BeautifulSoup.

Comment: the html file that I have downloaded does not contain any image. The html file only contains texts.

Comment: The html contains *the urls of the images*, in the `<img >` tags.

Comment: the last two segments of the code is search for the image and saves it in the local directory. But when I try to open it, the jpeg file produces an error after opening it. I also tried with htmlparser class(as instructed in the assignment) to extract any image inside the html file using below code but it does nothing:
def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag=="img":
        print(dict(attrs)["src"])
       
        image=open('pics.jpeg','w')
        image.write(dict(attrs)["src"])

Comment: The image file is not in your filesystem, so you can't just `open` it! You must download it, just like you downloaded the html page. That's what your browser does when he encounters an `<img >` tag.

Comment: Could you please provide the modified code? I can't seem to figure it out!!